# window server 2012 c# loop very slow

Tags: c#, windows, server

I have a c# console application with simple code like this:

```
string s = "monkeys!";
int dummy = 0;

System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(s);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    sb.Append(s);
s = sb.ToString();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
foreach (char c in s) dummy++;
//for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    dummy++;

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("MATRIX Elapsed={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

it takes 5 ms on my desktop with i5 CPU windows 7 but 13 ms on server 2012 with E5 2430 CPU.
this is just a test to test the loop performance since I met this problem in a big project using lots of loops.

I also tried windows 7 on that server, it's much faster than desktop.
so it seems it's about OS. what's wrong with windows server 2012?
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Server systems cannot really compared to desktop systems. Too many diffferences in system loads.

Comment: Servers are optimized to maximize I/O not single-thread operations like this.

Comment: But server's CPU is much more powerful right? At least server should not be slower? cause I tried windows 7 on that server, it's much faster. it seems it's OS problem @FailedUnitTest

Comment: First of all, the clock speed of Xeon E2430 is quite lower than most i5 CPUs, so single thread performance would automatically be lower. Second, Server OS prioritizes background tasks like IIS, Services, etc ahead of forefront applications. The point of a server OS (with default settings) is not to complete 1 task very fast, but to complete as many tasks as possible without choking. Also, http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Xeon-E5-2430-vs-Intel-Core-i5-3570K